# Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with image SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, model-view-controller, entity-framework-5

I get that error when I try to post a image in the database I thought it could of been a corrupt database so I redid the database but it is still the same, at first the table was `nvarchar`, I created a new table with the `image` datatype that is when I started to get the error.

```
// GET: StoreManager/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name");
    ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.Artists, "ArtistId", "Name");
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "AlbumId,GenreId,ArtistId,Title,Price,AlbumArtUrl")] Album album)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Albums.Add(album);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name", album.GenreId);
    ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.Artists, "ArtistId", "Name", album.ArtistId);

    return View(album);
}
```

Comment: Did you update the model to reflect the data type change (string => byte[]) ?

Comment: No i did not, sorry for the noob questions but i am new in MVC but which model? I have the Model PictureStoreEntities.cs and the Album.cs Model? Thanks.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Thanks changed it as you said now Im getting this error: 

Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.